# The Context of a git Patch

Tags: git

If I type the following

```
git show abckfirn49dj5ks94nsjy03hsev85esk9c32jt04
```

where `abckfirn49dj5ks94nsjy03hsev85esk9c32jt04` is a legitimate commit hash, git will show me something like the following

```
commit abckfirn49dj5ks94nsjy03hsev85esk9c32jt04
Author: Bob Jenkins <bjenkins@example.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 23 14:38:51 2018 -0700

    Commit message

diff --git a/somefile.txt b/agent/somefile.txt
index 54fc0544b..b7ce493a5 100644
--- a/somefile.txt
+++ b/somefile.txt
@@ -137,7 +137,6 @@ end:
 context
 context
+  an added line 
 context
 context
-  a deleted line
```

That is -- it shows me the commit hash, the commit author, the commit date, a commit message, **and a unix patch**.

I understand the unix patch format as a description of the differences *between two files*, presented in such a way that allows the unix `patch` command to reapply those differences

When I run `git show [commit hash]` -- what two files is git using to generate the patch.  I'm reasonably confident that one is the file at a particular hash, but is the other

1. The file at the current HEAD?
2. The file that immediately precedes the commit hash on the current branch?
3. Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I run `git show [commit hash]` -- what two files is git using to generate the patch?

The files are those identified by the `index` line:

> ```
> index 54fc0544b..b7ce493a5 100644
> ```

The hash ID on the left of the two dots is the (abbreviated, in this case) hash ID of the file stored as a *blob object*<sup>1</sup> in the parent commit, and the hash ID on the right is that of the file stored in the child commit.  (See below for a bit more of a pictorial diagram.)  The child commit is the one whose ID you passed to `git show`; the parent is its (lone) parent commit.  If there are multiple parent commits, `git show` will produce a *combined diff* by default, and the `index` line will list multiple left-side hash IDs.

Use `--full-index` to get the full hash ID of each blob.  Note that hash IDs are (currently) 40 hexadecimal characters, i.e., from the set `[0-9a-f]`.  These are the result of a 160-bit cryptographic hash applied to a header prefix followed by the file contents.  Hence two bit-for-bit identical files always produce the same hash ID, which makes it very easy for Git to skip diffing two files that are the same.  A commit that reuses most of the files from its parent commit, simply re-uses all of those blobs as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since *blob* was originally, in database jargon, short for Binary Large OBject, this word pair is brought to you by the Department of Redundancy Department.

---

A picture might be more explanatory.  Imagine the commit as a box containing a list of hash IDs.  The hash IDs identify where in the warehouse the files are.  The box itself has its own data as well: your name (and email address and so on), its parent commit, and so on; and the box gets a hash ID so that the box can be found in the warehouse:

```
fe0a9eaf31dd0c349ae4308498c33a5c3794b293 (a commit)
     +--------------------------------------------------+
     | parent: 8b026edac3104ecc40a68fd58b764fb3c717babb |
     | author: ...                                      |
     | more stuff: ...                                  |
     | contents: (long list of hash IDs)                |
     +--------------------------------------------------+

8b026edac3104ecc40a68fd58b764fb3c717babb (a commit)
     +--------------------------------------------------+
     | parent: ...                                      |
     | ...                                              |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
...

f17af66a97c8097ab91f074478c4a5cb90425725 (a blob)
     +--------------------------------------------------+
     | Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision contr |
     | ol system\n===================================== |
     | ...
     :
```

The *commit* boxes eventually (actually through intermediate boxes) contain the file names and hash IDs.  The *blob* boxes contain the actual file data, like Git's `README.md` quoted above.  Two different commits, with different box-ID labels, can contain the *same* file by just listing the same hash ID under the same filename.  If two different commits list *different* file contents, but under the same name, `git diff` will (normally)<sup>2</sup> compare those two files and produce the patching instructions for changing one file into the other.

---

<sup>2</sup>Git usually assumes that file `README.md` in commit `A` is the "same file" as `README.md` in commit `B`.  If you *rename* a file, Git has to find a file that has sufficiently similar contents to identify this as a rename operation.  You can also tell `git diff` to *break* the associations of files if they seem "too changed".  None of this is stuff you need to know to *use* Git, at least at first.

Comment: Thank you @torek -- +1 for useful information.  However -- one thing about your answer confused me -- *the hash ID on the right is that of the file stored in the child commit. The child commit is the one whose ID you passed to git show* -- in my case, that's not true.  The hash I asked for with `git show` is different from both the hash on the left and the hash on the right of the index line.  If you know, top of your head, how this is possible that would be useful information to add.  If not, no worries, you've given me more than enough to go on.

Comment: Each object in Git has its own hash: the *commit* has one (a Git object of type `commit`), and each file *contained within* the commit has its own (a Git object of type `blob`). This is necessary since a commit that re-uses a previous commit's blobs needs to re-use those blob IDs, but have its own separate commit ID. There's a layer sandwiched in between the commits and the blobs, for technical reasons, but you can ignore that for now.

Comment: Thanks again @torek!  I've been hearing people say for years that git is an object store, but the implications of that ever really clicked for me until now!

Answer (score 3):

Each commit object references a tree (which ultimately tells it which version of the file corresponds to that commit) and a pointer to the previous commit object.

The hash `abckfirn49dj5ks94nsjy03hsev85esk9c32jt04` corresponds to one of these commit objects, and this object will have a single `parent` field in its header pointing to its predecessor.

If you're interested in how this all works I recommend this page:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

and particularly this diagram:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/data-model-3.png

(deliberately not hotlinking)

EDIT: also the git community book: http://shafiulazam.com/gitbook/1_the_git_object_model.html

Comment: +1 for the useful information, especially the points to which part of the git book might help out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first file is the PFile (a variable term representing the current file in your project folder) before that commit. The second file is the PFile after that commit is applied.

> The file at the current HEAD?

```
git log  <hash>...HEAD --stat <file>
```

The three dots are important, an example:

```
git log  1c9fd7cb16df91a03dc43cea98ff05730ba51b5c...HEAD --stat gc/base/MemorySubSpace.cpp
```

If it displays nothing, that means the file is a PFile (current head), otherwise it will print a list of commits that replace the Pfile.

Seeing how git works (the hash of identical files is same), the second file will not be superseded in all future commits unless the PFile is actually modified.

To verify replace the `<hash>` with `<hash>~1` and you will see your present commit in the list.